# gensim is always trimming the vocabulary

Tags: python, gensim

I have a big dataset and I'm trying to run Word2Vec model on it, but the vocabulary is constantly lowered to just 28.

```
>>> model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, window=5, min_count=1,trim_rule=None, workers=4,sg=0, hs=1)
>>> len(model.wv.vocab)
28
```

I've tried with different setup of the constructor still the same.

My dataset consists of machine logs:

```
wc eventlog_dataset
  4421775 124189284 978608310 eventlog_dataset
```

I previously ran tfidf model on this same dataset and I know for sure that I have ~100k unique words.

When I use a different dataset in gensim I have no such problem, so I definately know that the problem is my dataset, but I don't know why exactly...

Here's a sample :

```
2017-05-16 10:55:58.91 CDT     3 61617032 Notification    Minor           Command error   sw_cli     {user super all {{0 8}} -1 10.0.188.216 3136} {Command: getfs  Error: Error: File Services is not configured on this array.} {}
2017-05-16 10:55:32.58 CDT     3 61616917 Notification    Minor           Command error   sw_cli     {user super all {{0 8}} -1 10.0.51.11 3727} {Command: getcage -e cage12 Error:    Opcode         = SCCMD_DOCDB    Node           = 253    Tpd error code = TE_INVALID          -- Invalid input parameter    Tpd error info = Cage (cage12) does not support this function } {}
```

As per the gensim documentation `trim_rule=None,min_count=1` should leave the full vocabulary.

Has anyone had such problems on datasets before ?

**EDIT**

Here's the code

```
class FileToSent(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
       def __iter__(self):
            for line in open(self.filename, 'r'):
             ll = [i for i in unicode(line, 'utf-8').lower().split()]
             print ll
            yield ll


    sentences = FileToSent('/home/veselin/eventlog_dataset')
    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, window=5, min_count=2,workers=4, hs=1)
```

And here's the output from the first line :

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/veselin/PycharmProjects/test/word2vec.py
[u'2016-10-16', u'17:55:19.55', u'cest', u'1', u'1788217', u'notification', u'minor', u'cli', u'command', u'error', u'sw_cli', u'{3parsvc', u'super', u'all', u'{{0', u'8}}', u'-1', u'172.16.24.110', u'12539}', u'{command:', u'getsralertcrit', u'all', u'error:', u'this', u'system', u'is', u'not', u'licensed', u'for', u'system', u'reporter', u'features}', u'{}']
```

You can see that words like cli,system or license, etc are not included in the vocabulary.

INFO logging (on full dataset)

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/veselin/PycharmProjects/test/word2vec.py
2017-07-28 11:32:56,966 : INFO : collecting all words and their counts
2017-07-28 11:33:35,580 : INFO : PROGRESS: at sentence #0, processed 0 words, keeping 0 word types
2017-07-28 11:33:35,582 : INFO : collected 28 word types from a corpus of 29 raw words and 1 sentences
2017-07-28 11:33:35,582 : INFO : Loading a fresh vocabulary
2017-07-28 11:33:35,582 : INFO : min_count=2 retains 1 unique words (3% of original 28, drops 27)
2017-07-28 11:33:35,582 : INFO : min_count=2 leaves 2 word corpus (6% of original 29, drops 27)
2017-07-28 11:33:35,583 : INFO : deleting the raw counts dictionary of 28 items
2017-07-28 11:33:35,584 : INFO : sample=0.001 downsamples 1 most-common words
2017-07-28 11:33:35,584 : INFO : downsampling leaves estimated 0 word corpus (3.3% of prior 2)
2017-07-28 11:33:35,584 : INFO : estimated required memory for 1 words and 100 dimensions: 1900 bytes
2017-07-28 11:33:35,584 : INFO : constructing a huffman tree from 1 words
2017-07-28 11:33:35,585 : INFO : built huffman tree with maximum node depth 0
2017-07-28 11:33:35,585 : INFO : resetting layer weights
2017-07-28 11:33:35,585 : INFO : training model with 4 workers on 1 vocabulary and 100 features, using sg=0 hs=1 sample=0.001 negative=5 window=5
2017-07-28 11:36:43,871 : INFO : PROGRESS: at 100.00% examples, 0 words/s, in_qsize 2, out_qsize 2
2017-07-28 11:36:43,872 : INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 3 more threads
2017-07-28 11:36:43,873 : INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 2 more threads
2017-07-28 11:36:43,873 : INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 1 more threads
2017-07-28 11:36:43,873 : INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 0 more threads
2017-07-28 11:36:43,873 : INFO : training on 145 raw words (0 effective words) took 188.3s, 0 effective words/s
2017-07-28 11:36:43,873 : WARNING : under 10 jobs per worker: consider setting a smaller `batch_words' for smoother alpha decay

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the vocabulary, to see what 'words' it's retaining?

Try evaluating/printing:

```
model.wv.index2word
```

When you see what all the 'words' have in common, check the `sentences` corpus you're supplying.

Is each individual item (sentence) a list-of-tokens, or a list-of-characters? Word2Vec expects the former: text that is already tokenized, rather than raw strings.

Comment: Here's the words @gojormo [**bold**]' >>> model.wv.index2word
[u'error:', u'all', u'is', u'{command:', u'cdt', u'array', u'notification', u'10.0.188.216', u'3', u'-1', u'3445}', u'{hbezanson', u'minor', u'8}}', u'federation', u'sw_cli', u'10:55:58.92', u'{}', u'member.}', u'61617033', u'not', u'super', u'a', u'2017-05-16', u'{{0', u'getfed', u'command', u'error'] '**bold**

Comment: If those are the only words in your vocabulary, then those are the only words you supplied in `sentences`. Check what `sentences` contains. What word(s) appear in one of the `sentences` items that you expect to see, and which don't?

Comment: I checked the sentences and it contains a list of words just like it is suppose to work.So it's not that.

Comment: What word(s) appear in one of the `sentences` items that you expect to see, and which don't? Show some code which proves that word is a token in one  of the items in `sentences`.

Comment: I've added the example in my questions.Please take a look at it.

Comment: There's no full definition of `FileToSent`. But the `break` in your `__iter__()` means only one line will ever be returned. 28 tokens, and the list of vocabulary you shared, seems like about the number that might appear in a single log line. If you turn on INFO logging during Word2Vec training, you'd also likely see progress-reporting/model-stats that make it clear you're not feeding it more than 28 unique tokens.

Comment: Sorry the break was intentional, just to stop it from iterating the whole thing...I'm editing my question with the INFO logging.

Comment: The INFO logging shows that your `sentences` provides only 1 item, with 29 words, 28 of which are unique. Your (latest) `min_count=2` tells `Word2Vec` to discard all but the one word with 2 occurrences. If you change back to `min_count=1` you'll again have 28 words. But `sentences` still doesn't contain all the lines you expect it to - that's the bug you'll have to fix. (Maybe it's still using a variant of the iterable with the `break`?)

Answer (score 0):

It has been passed some times, but I hope this can still help somebody.

If I correctly understood your issue, you want all the words of your file to be in w2v vocabulary.
If so, you should define a trim_rule that keeps all the words and pass it to the "build_vocab" function.

Here is an example:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.utils import RULE_KEEP

documents_list = [["first", "document"], ["second", "document"]]

def _rule(word, count, min_count): # params are needed
    return RULE_KEEP

model = Word2Vec()
# model = Word2Vec.load("path_to_your_pretrained_model") # if you are using a pre-trained w2v model

model.build_vocab(documents_list, trim_rule=_rule) # use update=True if the model has already been trained e.g. pre-trained models

print(model.wv.vocab) 
# should print something like 
# {'first':<gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x17a34271b88>,
#  'document':<gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x17a31737e88>,
#  'second': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x17a31737ec8>}

model.train(documents_list, total_examples=len(documents_list), epochs=model.epochs)
print(model.most_similar("first"))
# should give
# [('second', 0.026407353579998016), ('document', -0.04318903386592865)]
```

build_vocab function doc (see trim_rule and update parameters) [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.build_vocab)